# why percentile() method is not calculating the appropriate percentile? Like the 25th percentile for this data should be 1.5 and 2 if rounded off

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = np.percentile(value, 25)

print(x)
```

I am calculating percentile using this code to cross verify

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from numpy import math

def my_percentile(data, percentile):
    n = len(data)
    p = n * percentile / 100
    if p.is_integer():
        return sorted(data)[int(p)]
    else:
        return sorted(data)[int(math.ceil(p)) - 1]

t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
per = my_percentile(t, 25)

print(per)
```

Comment: How did you determine that the 25th percentile should be 1.5? Think about the result of this expression: `np.percentile(Value, [0,25,50,75,100])`.

Comment: Check the updated code, that's how I am calculating percentile using the traditional mathematical formula.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to calculate quartiles. [Wikipedia has a good summary under *quantiles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile).

The values returned by numpy's default calculation match those returned by, for example, R's `summary()` function.

You need to do one of these things.

- Switch to numpy.percentile's default way of calculating quartiles,
- provide a value to numpy.percentile's parameter `interpolation`, or
- write your own custom function.

Valid values for `interpolation` in numpy.percentile are [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html).

I didn't suggest a value for `interpolation`, because you didn't include your expected output in your question. You need to consider the effect of your decision on all quartiles, not just on one.

(I don't think `scipy.stats.percentileofscore()` will work for you.